# haskell: Get Data in Parsec IO

Tags: haskell, extract, monads

I have read in a csv File via Parsec and Data.CSV:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
-- package MissingH
import Data.CSV 
import Data.Either.Utils
myFile <- parseFromFile csvFile path
```

This seems to give me something of type

```
IO (Either ParseError [[String]])
```

Now i want to do a lot of stuff on my list of lists.
For a start i need to map a split on it, since my csv is tab-seperated.

**How do i extract the List from this type-structure?**

I already found

import Data.Either
   fromRights

Comment: Did you implement `csvFile` yourself? If so, show us how. Otherwise, tell us  where you got it from (edit your question and add your imports).

Comment: with `fmap` or `>>=`.

Comment: @rightfold can you give an application example?

Comment: @NicolasAntor As far as I know, no module called `Data.CSV` is available on Hackage. However, there are [`Data.Csv`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Csv.html) and [`Text.CSV`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-0.1.2/docs/Text-CSV.html) modules. Did you mean one of those two? Besides, `myFile <- parseFromFile csvFile path` is illegal outside a `do` block. You should always post self-contained, minimal, working code.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.3.0.1/docs/Data-CSV.html

Answer (score 2):

You may just pattern-match on it* - you can ignore the `IO` layer as you are already working in the I/O monad:

```
main = do
  myFile <- parseFromFile csvFile path
  case myFile of
    Left _ -> error "parse error" -- do something useful here
    Right list -> print $ doMyProcessing list -- process your list here
```

*I'm not sure about your knowledge level, so I've given a fairly minimal answer. Ask for more explanation if you need it.

Comment: yeah here it would work. But if i want to use a other function from outside of the monad?

Comment: You can't "get out of" the I/O monad (this is deliberate). You can either give `list`, a pure value, to another function (such as `doMyProcessing` in the example), or return an `IO [[String]]` and use it in another function in the I/O monad.

Comment: So i can't use a function of type String -> Char -> [String] in IO?

Comment: @NicolasAntor IO means that this isn't actually any list, but an action that may be performed to get a list. That is what IO is, the monad of actions.

Comment: @NicolasAntor Another way to think of it, is, how do you get data out of the Reader monad?